# PHP's square brackets: when to put quotes and when not?

Tags: php, variables, post, quotes, brackets

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['posted'])) {
if ($_POST['question1'] == "Lisbon") {
  echo "You are correct, $_POST[question1] is the right answer<hr>";
}

if ($_POST['question1'] != "Lisbon") {
  echo "You are incorrect, $_POST[question1] is not. the right answer<hr>";
}
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="quiz.php">
<input type="hidden" name="posted" value="true">
What is the capital of Portugal?
<br>
<br>
<input name=''question1" type=''radio" value=''Porto''>
Porto
<br>
<input name=''question1" type="radio" value=''Lisbon''>
Lisbon
<br>
<input name="question1" type="radio" value=''Madrid''>
Madrid
<br>
<br>
<input type=''submit''>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the whole part, it's from a PDF. Thing is though, they didn't specified why they used ' ' for the question1 in the if statement but no quotes in the echo statement.

In a nutshell: why $_POST['question1'] has ' ' in the if statement 
and why $_POST[question1] doesn't have in the echo statement. They are the same variable.
Thank you.

Comment: For array values, the key can be a string (with quotes) or a number. For writing array values inside double-quoted strings, no quote is needed. See http://php.net/string  (scroll down to "variable parsing").

Comment: Not related, but it looks like some of your attribute quotes are messed up, using `''` (two single quotes) instead of `"` (one double quote). Not sure if that's just an error in your post or if it's in your actual code, but you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Always* use quotes (for string keys), unless inside a double quoted string. See [the string parsing section](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) of the manual.

```
$juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");

echo "He drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some $juices[1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some juice made of $juice[0]s.".PHP_EOL; // Won't work
echo "He drank some $juices[koolaid1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I actually didn't know that `$juices[koolaid1]` was valid in this context. It looks so sloppy, like it can't be right. Personally I rarely use double quotes unless I need control characters or something.

Comment: `$juice = $juices[0]` <-- just fine as well

Comment: @Wesley, I agree that it looks bad. PHP has peculiar interpolation rules. I prefer `{$juices['koolaid1']}` or avoiding such syntax altogether.

Comment: Yep, I believe avoiding this syntax altogether is usually best. Like in this case, they aren't escaping the post data. In order to do so you'd have to concatenate or prepare another variable.

Answer (score 0):

The characters of the array key are literals, so text should have single quotes. Integer keys should never have quotes.

Here are the finer details:

- When the array key starts with an alphabetical character, PHP will "understand" that you meant to put single quotes if you didn't put them. So `$var[key]` will be interpreted as `$var['key']`.
- Inside double-quoted strings, surround array variables with curly brackets to avoid issues. This works in HEREDOCS too! `echo "Your ID is {$user['id']}."`.
- You can use double quotes, but it is recommended not to unless you are doing variable interpolation, i.e. `$var["someKey$num"]`. Even in this case, better to use `$var['someKey'.$num]` or `$var["someKey{$num}"]`.